# Azure Service Editor config changes are not applicated

Tags: azure, editor

I have a problem with my QnA Bot App. I made some changes to basic responses (No answer found, Hello and Goodbye) in Azure Service Editor. I have also changed a default HTML webpage. Changes made in a HTML website were made instantly, but the config files with new welcome responses were not.

I am sure that I once watched a tutorial that provided information that after you change some stuff in configs files you need to commit them using Kudo Console. I tried restarting the app but it did not work.

I am beginner. Does anyone remember what is the command?
I tried searching through my whole browser history but I still cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

I used command deploy and it worked.